# Encrypt and decrypt large file with AES

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I am trying to **encrypt** a large file with **AES**, then **decrypt** it and compare with the original.

This class summarizes the work. It works OK for .txt files, **but NOT** for .mp3, .pdf and so on.

Help will be very appreciated.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class LargeFileEncryptionTest7 {

    protected static String FOLDER_PATH = "C:/temp/";
    protected static String FILE = "some-large-file";
    protected static String EXT = ".mp3"; //Works for .txt, but not for .mp3 or .pdf

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //Load file to encrypt
        byte[] largeFileBytes = loadFile(FOLDER_PATH + FILE + EXT);
        String largeFileString = new String(largeFileBytes);

        //Encrypt file with AES
        AESUtils aesUtils = new AESUtils();
        byte[] secretKey = aesUtils.generateSecretKey();
        aesUtils.setSecretKey(secretKey);
        byte[] largeFileEncBytes = aesUtils.encrypt(largeFileString);

        //Save encrypted file
        saveFile(largeFileEncBytes, FOLDER_PATH + FILE + "-encrypted" + EXT);

        //Load encrypted file
        byte[] largeFileEncBytesToCheck = loadFile(FOLDER_PATH + FILE + "-encrypted" + EXT);

        //Decrypt file      
        byte[] largeFileBytesToCheck = aesUtils.decrypt(largeFileEncBytesToCheck);
        String largeFileStringToCheck = new String(largeFileBytesToCheck);

        //Save decrypted file
        saveFile(largeFileBytesToCheck, FOLDER_PATH + FILE + "-decrypted" + EXT);

        //Check strings
        //System.out.println("Original content: " + largeFileStringToCheck);
        if (largeFileStringToCheck.equals(largeFileString)) {
            System.out.println("OK  :-) ");
        } else {
            System.out.println("KO  :-( ");
        }                       
    }

    private static void saveFile(byte[] bytes, String fileName) throws Exception {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        fos.write(bytes);
        fos.close();
    }

    private static byte[] loadFile(String fileName) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        int numBtyes = fis.available();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[numBtyes];
        fis.read(bytes);
        fis.close();
        return bytes;
    }

}
```

Comment: You should rule out encoding as a factor. Either explicitly mention the encoding everywhere or just dont use the old cumbersome file api anymore but NIO. Your `loadFile` method for example, replace it by `Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName))`, thats it. And it will always use UTF-8. Similar for `saveFile`, just `Files.write(Paths.get(fileName), bytes)`, done. Also mention the encoding when creating your strings `new String(bytes, StandardCharset.UTF_8)`. Just make sure it is the same encoding everywhere, otherwise you will run into issues.

Comment: Last, dont compare the strings. Compare the raw data, the `byte[]`s, otherwise you are relying on encoding again. If the bytes are still equal, then the encryption/decryption went well and it is just you not specifying the correct encoding for a string-representation.

Comment: Trying to convert arbitrary binary data to a `String` seems like a bad idea. Does `AESUtils` have a method that accepts a `byte[]` as input? If not, can you add one?

Comment: As Michael says. And "bad idea" is an *understatement.* Any lib / util that promises to perform encryption on `String`s is either bound to fail you (e.g. provided by someone who does not have a clue), or making assumptions that you should be aware of by reading the documentation (it works only when the String input Base64 encoded strings, for example). Encryption is a byte-level process, not char-level. And  again, stressing the previous point, converting any binary to a String (without even specifying a encoding) is *asking* for data corruption, and will someday crash. Don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is interested I put here final solution.

It is inspired in some of the comments people done. Mainly avoid the use of Strings and work with byte[]:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class LargeFileEncryptionTest11 {

    private static final String FOLDER_PATH = "C:/temp/";
    private static final String FILE = "some-large-file";
    private static final String EXT = ".pdf";

    private static final String ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM = "AES";
    private static final int KEY_SIZE = 128; // 192 and 256 bits may not be available

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //Common stuff to encrypt/decrypt
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance(ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM);
        kgen.init(KEY_SIZE); 
        SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
        byte[] secretKey = skey.getEncoded();
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey, ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM);

        //Load file to encrypt
        byte[] largeFileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(FOLDER_PATH + FILE + EXT));

        //Encrypt file
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] largeFileEncBytes = cipher.doFinal(largeFileBytes);

        //Save encrypted file
        Files.write(Paths.get(FOLDER_PATH + FILE + "-encrypted" + EXT), largeFileEncBytes);

        //Load encrypted file
        byte[] largeFileEncBytesToCheck = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(FOLDER_PATH + FILE + "-encrypted" + EXT));

        //Decrypt file      
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] largeFileBytesToCheck = cipher.doFinal(largeFileEncBytesToCheck);

        //Save decrypted file
        Files.write(Paths.get(FOLDER_PATH + FILE + "-decrypted" + EXT), largeFileBytesToCheck);

        //Compare results
        if (Arrays.equals(largeFileBytes, largeFileBytesToCheck)) {
            System.out.println("OK  :-) ");
        } else {
            System.out.println("KO  :-( ");
        }                       
    }

}
```

Comment: This solution has the major disadvantage that it requires at least twice the size of the file in RAM. Hence considering the title of the question ("large" can mean several GB and more) this solution is not well designed.

Comment: For our project I think it can work. We only need to encrypt mp3 recordings of about 15 minutes maximum.

Answer (score 3):

I see 2 issues with your solution:

Your code:

> ```
>    int numBtyes = fis.available();
>     byte[] bytes = new byte[numBtyes];
>     fis.read(bytes);
> ```

This actually doesn't guarantee the whole content is read. As well when encrypting large files (when there's no guarantee it will fit into memory), then you may not want to read all the content into memory.

When encrypting / decrypting large content (unlimited), you may want to use something like:

```
byte[] buff = new byte[BUFFERSIZE];
for(int readBytes=in.read(buff); readBytes>-1;readBytes=in.read(buff)) {
  out.write(cipher.update(buff,0, readBytes);
}
out.write(cipher.doFinal());
```

or have a look at CipherOutputStream and [CipherInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/CipherInputStream.html)

Another issue is comparing:

> ```
> String largeFileStringToCheck = new String(largeFileBytesToCheck);
> ```

As already commented, this is a terrible way to compare content. In Java the String is intended only for printable characters, when trying to "stringify" any byte array, an encoding is applied and non-printable characters may be "trashed".

for simple comparison (having byte arrays), you may use [Arrays.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(byte[],%20byte[])) method

When comparing REALLY large content (when you may be not sure it will fit into your RAM memory), usually it is a good idea to create a [message hash](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) and compare the hashes

Edit: if you really want to see/print/compare the ciphertext as string, you may encode the binary data, you may have a look at the [Base64 encoding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html).